How to disable not found logging as error
Application insights logging is enabled on our APIM with 'always log errors' on and Verbosity on 'error'. We noticed that a 404 is logged as an error with these settings if we go to the 'failures' screen on application insights for our application.
Is there any way to exclude the 404 logging as an error on APIM? The application it self using a custom ITelemetryInitializer to mark the 404's as successful.
Update (example):

Update: APIM event in AI

Please provide more details about the issue.

How you are logging traces ? Have you configured code related to ApplicationInsights from app ?

i added a screenshot with an example.

Is this 404 error populating from any api's test result?

No it's coming from legit calls. APIM logging is marking the call as 'successful request = false'.

Have you added any policy in apim? If you have only enabled application insight in apim without any other changes then you shouldn't get this. Try to test the API present/imported in apim and see what is result you are getting, the same request will be logged in app insight

@IkhtesamAfrin, can you please clarify what you mean by policies in this case? Are you saying that there is some policy which will change this behavior? Which one?

@Nils, great question! It might make sense to provide feedback to APIM team. At the bottom of their official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights?tabs=rest) there is a link which will allow you to create a new ask. Please paste it here and I'll upvote it!


Primarily, If you have only enabled application insight to log error which are coming from APIM then you can't directly get 404 error unless you have invoked any operation present in the APIM instance and the same must have returned 404 error.

In order to verify this, you can navigate to API -> Any operation -> Go to Test. If you are getting 200 status code then it will not log in application insight. In my case, I am getting 500 internal server error which is being logged in application insight.




You might get 404 error if your APIM instance failed to identify either an API or operation but you can't ignore/avoid this error from being logged instead if you want to return an alternate response with a different status code then you can do so by using the policy shared in this blog.


My understanding of the question - for legitimate 404 responses not to log them as failures (both for not polluting telemetry and for not paying for such logs since sampling is at 1% but these logs skip it). This is standard for Application Insights (to treat 404 as success). I don't think APIM supports it though.

There is a limitation in APIM in regards to 404 errors, refer the blog link I have added in the post. Secondly you can test it the way I am doing to see the response message and same you will see in app insight

I think the question was for legitimate 404s. APIM should return 404 but log to Application Insights as success (and also apply sampling).

Yes I understood but APIM doesn't treat it as success. APIM only considers 200 as success

Exactly.  So, this should be an ask to APIM team to support this.

Yes, you need to raise this issue with product team
