Supress 404 error as fault in Api Management Service in Application Insights
We have an Api Management Service running with Application Insights integration which is running perfectly fine.
However one of the endpoints (which has a restfull api as backend) could potentially return a 404 response which is a valid response for that endpoint meaning that the resource does not exist. However that 404 response is logged in Application Insights as a fault and shown as failure.
Is it possible to override the behavior to log that specific 404 case not as a failure? Similar like you could in .net (How to tell Application Insights to ignore 404 responses). The api is not controlled by me and to be honest I think a 404 is a valid response in this case.

Would you like to return the status as 200 in place of 404? @MaartenKieft

I want that the 404 is not logged as fault. I could ofcourse let the api management service return a 200 if it gets a 404 from the backend, but that is still logged as fault as far as I know.

If response code is 200 then it will be logged as success in app insight but other than this all the status code will be logged as failure in app insight. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79199126/how-to-disable-not-found-logging-as-error/79202022#79202022 @MaartenKieft

I have managed to get 404 resource not found in APIM and indeed it is getting logged as failure in application insight.
This is the expected behavior of APIM wherein it will mark the request as successful for 200 status code only but apart from this, all the other status code will be logged as failure.

Then, I added below policy in operation level and the same you can add in API level also which will alter the status code to 200 in place of 404.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 404)">
                <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

After using this policy, my request got logged as successful but under the hood, the dependency in application insight will give you the actual status code and message which is coming from backend as shown below.


In this way, you can mark the request as successful in application insight.
